# Message: Trying to get property of non-object while passing data from cotroller to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wrote function in model as:

```
public function select()
{
    $this->db->select('*');    
    $this->db->from('students');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

And controller as:

```
public function edit()
{
    $data['row']=$this->student_model->select();
    //print_r($data['row']);
    $this->load->view('edit.php',$data);
}
```

It could print data in controller function..But while passing into the view page I'm getting the error message as:

```
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
```

Comment: Where is your views code???

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo your data in edit page like this for every fields

```
echo $row[0]->field_name;
```